# Why do I get a TypeError if I pass only one argument?

Tags: python, typeerror, except

```
def divide(num1,num2):
    try:
        return num1/num2
    except TypeError:
        return "Please provide two integers or floats"
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "Please do not divide by zero"
```

Comment: You don't enter the body of the function if you don't pass the two positional argument it requires. You can't catch that *inside* the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OMG this is the first question I dared to ask, you replied straight away and I understood your reply! How can I express my gratitude? I see only a flag next to your reply!

Comment: @nadjmental, if you think  his answer helps you then upvote it, don't trigger flag/

Comment: I've turned it into an answer now, that was just a comment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe apparently votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score - anyway thank you very much!

Comment: @nadjmental you're right, that's in https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers guidance - *"if you have earned the appropriate voting privilege..."*

Comment: @TaohidulIslam same for you, votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score, thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @nadjmental, You can accept the best answer by clicking on the green checkmark beside the answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I read your link and it also says not too add a comment to say "Thank you", oopsie ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't supply all of the required arguments, the function is never entered, so there's no way to catch that `TypeError` from *inside* the function.

To illustrate, consider a function that immediately errors out:

```
>>> def func(a, b, c):
...     raise Exception("inside the function")
...
```

Now let's call it with the required arguments:

```
>>> func(1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in func
Exception: inside the function
```

Here you can see from the traceback (`in func`) that the function was entered and the error thrown from there. However, if we call it again without the arguments:

```
>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

Note that the traceback doesn't include `in func`, the error happens *before* entering the function body. You can only catch it *outside* the function:

```
>>> try:
...     func()
... except TypeError:
...     print('oh no!')
...
oh no!
```

Answer (score 0):

For positional parameters, you have to pass the same number of arguments. You can use the default argument concept, like :

```
def divide(num1=1,num2=1):
    try:
        return num1/num2
    except TypeError:
        return "Please provide two integers or floats"
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "Please do not divide by zero"
```

You can call this function using 0,1 or 2 arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Because your try/except statement is catching that exception and returning the designated message.

Try something like this:

```
try:
   if num1 and num2:
      return num1 / num2
   else:
      return "Please provide two numbers"
except ZeroDivisionError:
   return "Please do not divide by zero"
except TypeError:
   return "Please provide two integers or floats"
```